# How do you autofocus the input box in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm using the gifted chat library and want to autofocus on the input with the keyboard up on initial render.  I see that there is an imperative function `focusTextInput` but how do I call it?

```
<GiftedChat
  {...props}
  messages={this.state.messages}
  ref={(chat) => this.chat = chat }
  onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
  user={{
      _id: 1,
  }}
/>
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat)

I tried setting the `ref` and calling it directly on did mount but that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the library already has `textInputProps`

> **textInputProps** (Object) - Extra props to be passed to the `TextInput`

Therefore you can use [`autoFocus`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus) prop of the `TextInput`

```
<GiftedChat
      textInputProps={{autoFocus: true}}
      messages={this.state.messages}
      onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
      user={{
             _id: 1,
       }}
  />
```